# Trying to emit only to a room in socket.io but it emits to everyone connected to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io

Here is my connection function where I add the socket to the SOCKET_LIST global so I can iterate through it later.

Player.onConnect does initialization which will create a new room if none are open or join one if someone is waiting for an oponent.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {


    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

    Player.onConnect(socket);

});
```

then this is where I try emitting all the data to users in the same room.. but instead of just emitting the data to people in the room it winds up emitting data to everyone connected to the server.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var pack = {
        player:Player.update(),
        platform:Platform.update()
    }
   for (var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('newPositions', pack);
    }

}, 30);
```

When I console.log out the room ids from the server it works accordingly, like i'll join from 2 clients and then the third one will console out a new room id, and then the 5th one, etc. Since the game is suppose to be a 2 player game and a new room is created if someone else tries to join a game.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in SOCKET_LIST)
```

loops over your SOCKET_LIST and gets all sockets that is why the server emits to everyone.